# Running the bash file from url using PHP curl (CURLOPT_URL)

Tags: bash, webserver

I am working on to run the bash file from url using the PHP curl but when i run this it will show me the content of the bash file but not run the bash file.

bash file with name install.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash
 composer install package-name dev-master
```

Php File content

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://myprject/install.sh');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

Output:

## !/bin/bash composer install package-name dev-master

as a text not script run or package install

Comment: Does the script run if you open it in a browser? I think the web server isn't correctly configured. Do you use apache?

Comment: What do you expect, that the script runs on your server or on your client?

Comment: @Bayou if i directly hit the script from browser it download the .sh file. but on the curl it return the output as text.

Comment: @jeb On my server as i want to run it from a url so i can access it from any place like a remote api

Comment: If you want to run the script on your server, you must enable the web server to run shell scripts. Same goes for some other executable. Do you use Apache?

Comment: Then your question is unrelated to curl, php and also to composer. The webserver should start your shell script independent of the user agent

Comment: @bayou i am using the nginx server but if run it from php shell_script it run

Comment: @jeb but why as it used the curl and php

Comment: I don't think you can execute a bash script with php. It will probably just spit out the content of the file rather than execute it. The difference between running something locally and calling a remote url to execute a script is that you have to _configure_ the web server to execute shell scripts along php scripts. I suggest you search `how to configure CGI for Nginx` in your favourite search engine. It will not work otherwise.

Comment: @NavjotSingh The server doesn't care about how you requested the URL. It should always start the script, independent if it's called by curl, chrome or ...